# Avoid template to be destroyed when changing routes

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to avoid a template destruction when changing routes in iron-router?   Since my template is all reactive but a little bulky, I want to keep it "behind the scenes" (in memory)  while going to other templates and just show it when the route come back without re-creating everything (it is builded through several mongo/minimongo collection queries that add delays to the user experience).

I can think in some workarounds like hide/show DOM objects (awful solution) or make my route a home route and nest all other routes inside (not so good) but I wonder if there is a native way to accomplish that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here's an article](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography) I wrote that you might find useful. It describes how to use unmanaged mongo collections on the client to cache data. This can help you deal with long creation times for objects you want to display.

Comment: Michael, interesting article.  Currently I'm loading my data from a local collection in minimongo (no server involved, since I'm testing it offline) and the local reading and rendering is taking too much time for my template, thats why I'm looking for a way to keep my template in memory after the first load despite of changing routes.

Comment: Are you defining your collection with `MyCol = new Meteor.Collection()`? If you're providing a name then you still have a collection on the server. If not then the collection only exists in client memory. Rendering is cheap. Computations from mongo can be expensive.

Comment: Actually my collection is from server: `Members = new Mongo.Collection("members")`.  However the delay I have noticed even happens when I disconnect my server and only work with the minimongo version on client memory.  The delay is the same with subscription ready and server connected or disconnected.

Comment: If your code is "rebuilding" data when the template is being rendered then your caching strategy is not working, agreed?

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuilding data"?  I just query two collections (not updates/deletes) in order to render.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136903/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-ruben).